# MyQuery to compare with other table and get record and if there is no record in second table it should place zero

Tags: mysql

I have two table tbl_user and tbl_friend. In tbl_friend the fields user_id and friend_id are both foreign key from tbl_user and 'friend_request' field is 1 if one send the request to other. Now I want all the users from tbl_user and if it is the friend of id=1(primary key of tbl_user)then select 'friend_request' from tbl_friend. If it is not a friend of id=1 then return 0.

**tbl_user is**

```
id | name
---------
1  | Abc
2  | Pqr
3  | Def
4  | xyz
5  | Lmn
```

**tbl_friend is**

```
in_id | user_id | friend_id | friend_request
--------------------------------------------
1     | 2       |  1        |2
2     | 3       |  1        |1
3     | 4       |  3        |1
4     | 1       |  4        |1
```

Now I fired **query**

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `friend_request`, `user_id`, `friend_id`
FROM `tbl_user`
LEFT JOIN tbl_friends AS f ON f.user_id = id
OR f.friend_id = id
WHERE id<>"1"
GROUP BY `id`
UNION ALL
SELECT `id`
FROM friends AS f
LEFT JOIN `user` ON f.user_id = id
OR f.friend_id = id
WHERE user_id =1 OR friend_id =1
GROUP BY `id`
```

The **result is**

```
id | name | friend_request | user_id |friend_id
-----------------------------------------------
2  | Pqr  | 2              |2        | 1
3  | Def  | 1              |3        | 1
4  | xyz  | 1              |4        | 3
5  | Lmn  |  Null          |Null     |Null
```

**I want this record**
`4  | xyz  | 1              |4       | 3`

**as**

`4  | xyz  | 1              |1       | 4`

**i.e** in the group by it takes the first record but I want the record which is a friend of id=1.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Another victim of mysql's non standard GROUP BY

Comment: what is the table `friends`? I suspect that this isn't your real query.  Please post your real query

Comment: @e4c5 I don't understand the question, moving on...

Comment: thank you @TimBiegeleisen for reminding me of the best strategy for these questions

Comment: friends is tbl_friend

Comment: See JOIN and COALESCE- also, the title doesn't match the question